# Is there a way to preview a fragment being used in another view in IntelliJ IDEA 12?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-fragments, preview

I recently made the switch from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA 12. Is there a good way to preview a fragment being used in another xml layout file?

In Eclipse there's a way to specify which fragment I'm using which is pretty helpful.

[image]

**Edit (clarification)**:
What I'm referring to is the ability to view a Fragment being referenced in another xml layout. Say I'm creating a Profile screen (activity_profile.xml) and want to include a fragment (fragment_pic.xml) that contains a picture, name, etc. When I include the fragment in the activity_profile.xml, it doesn't display in the preview for the activity_profile layout. It just displays "<fragment>"

Comment: I don't understand what "fragment being used in a view" means.  Can you clarify?

Comment: he probably means in a layout through xml

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can do this in the XML:

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.yourpackage.yourapp.yourfragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_layout" 
</fragment>
```

The tools namespace is qualified by this in the top view, same as xmlns:android namespace qualifier:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

I had this same issue as well after moving from Eclipse to the Android Studio Preview though thankfully Android Studio suggests you provide this in the XML when it checks your definitions, very handy :)

Comment: Apparently the preview started working in a recent Android Studio update. I didn't change any code, and it's now working. I'd imagine this xml namespace is still required, so I'll accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean the GUI designer.  To switch between xml view and designer view, click on the buttons circled in red.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I found this feature. I'm looking specifically for a feature in Eclipse where you can preview what a referenced fragment looks like in another xml layout (e.g. Fragment A being used in Layout 1)